# How to flatten my RECORD field that is made of repeated fields in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My table has a nested object (record) with a few array (repeated) properties.

there are 4 properties that are nested:

```
BM.HISTORY.AutoBill.BaseRate
BM.HISTORY.AutoBill.Substatus
BM.HISTORY.AutoBill.Services
BM.HISTORY.AutoBill.Conditions
```

[image]

Each property contains data like these

```
[
 {Label: "Completed....", Amount: 34.3, Quantity: 2}, 
 {Label: "Completed....", Amount: 34.3, Quantity: 2}
,...]
```

I'd like to extract a simple flat csv like this

```
OrderId  StartWindow                 Type       Label                      Quantity Amount
123      2022-07-17 13:07:00 UTC     BaseRate   Completed @ 100%           0        82.6
123      2022-07-17 13:07:00 UTC     Services   service 1                  1        16.1323
123      2022-07-17 13:07:00 UTC     Services   service 2                  1        5
123      2022-07-17 13:07:00 UTC     Conditions 10% Time Window Premium    0.826    8.26

234      2022-07-17 13:07:00 UTC     BaseRate   Completed @ 100%           0        3.6
234      2022-07-17 13:07:00 UTC     Services   service 1                  1        16.1323
234      2022-07-17 13:07:00 UTC     Services   service 2                  1        5
234      2022-07-17 13:07:00 UTC     Conditions 10% Time Window Premium    0.826    8.26
```

- Where StartWindow is a simple field of my table.
- Type is a tag I create based on *BILL.XXXX* from the for properties above and the other 3 columns will be flattened records inside each array.
- **they need to stack as rows**

This is what I have done but I **cannot** flatten it all in a simple csv.

```sql
SELECT
  Id as OrderId, StartWindow, Billing
FROM
  `xxx.xxxx.xxDB ADDRESSxxx`,
  UNNEST([ 
      (BM.HISTORY.BILL.BaseRate,'BASE RATE'),
      (BM.HISTORY.BILL.Substatus,'SUBSTATUS'),
      (BM.HISTORY.BILL.Services,'SERVICES'),
      (BM.HISTORY.BILL.Conditions,'CONDITIONS')
    ]
  ) as Billing
LIMIT 10
```

As you can see the result is **not** perfectly flattened.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code

```
select x from 
 UNNEST([ 
      ([1,2,3],'BASE RATE'),
      ([5,6],'SUBSTATUS')
 ]) x
```

generates first an array of two entries and the unpacks it into two rows. The first column is an array, the other column is the string name.

Therefore, the first column needs to be unnested again. In the following example this is done by  `unnest(x.dataset) as dataset`. The columns `A` to `C` correspond to `BaseRate` and `Substatus`.

```
With tbl as 
(
Select  1 id, "name1" as name, [struct("label1" as label,500 as amount),("t",1)] A,[("B1",20)] B , [("C1",1)] C
union all select 2, "name2",[("A2",2)],[("B2",10)] , null
union all select 3,"-",[],null ,null
union all select 4,"-",[],null ,[("test4",100),("test5",500)]
)

Select id,type,dataset.* from tbl,
unnest([
  struct(A as dataset,'A' as type),struct(B,'B'),struct(C,'C')
]) as x, unnest(x.dataset) as dataset
```

Another way of solving this task is to  unnested each record by itself:

```
SELECT Id, BaseRate.*, Substatus, Services, Conditions
FROM `xxx.xxxx.xxDB ADDRESSxxx`,
  UNNEST(BM.HISTORY.BILL.BaseRate) as BaseRate,
  UNNEST(BM.HISTORY.BILL.Substatus) as Substatus,
  UNNEST(BM.HISTORY.BILL.Services) as Services,
  UNNEST(BM.HISTORY.BILL.Conditions) as Conditions
```

However, here all combination of all entries are given out.

Thus there is a joining needed as well and the `unnest` is to be combinded `WITH OFFSET` to obtain the entry number.

I will show the route on an easy example. The table `tbl` has an id column, the columns `A` and `B` contain records of values. The column `C` contains a record of struct. Thus your column `BaseRate` is column `C`.

Each row of the `tbl` table has to be shown several time, to include all entries of the columns `A`, `B`, `C`.

We query the table `tbl` and calculate the times this row has to be shown: The `GREATEST` for the `array_lenght` of the columns `A`, `B`, `C` gives this information. The `unnest` and `generate_array` duplicates the needed rows for each id and includes an `entry` column counting from zero upwards.

For column `A` the values are unnested and joined to the `entry` column. The same is done for the `B` and `C` column.

Due to the join to the `entry` column there are no combination between the entries of the differen columns.`

Since column `C_` is a structure, `C_.*` unpacks this and gives all entries out directly.

```
With tbl as 
(
Select  1 id, "name1" as name, [1,2,3,4,5] A,[10,11] B , [struct("label1" as label,500 as amount),("t",1)] C
union all select 2, "name2",[7,8],[20,21,22] , null
union all select 3,"-",[],null ,null
union all select 4,"-",[],null ,[("test",100),("test5",500)]
)

select id,entry,name,A_,B_ ,C_.*
from tbl,
unnest(generate_array(0,GREATEST(1,ifnull(array_length(A),0),ifnull(array_length(B),0),ifnull(array_length(C),0))-1)) as entry

left join 
unnest(A) as A_ WITH OFFSET as A_offset
on A_offset=entry

left join 
unnest(B) as B_ WITH OFFSET as B_offset
on B_offset=entry

left join 
unnest(C) as C_ WITH OFFSET as C_offset
on C_offset=entry
```

Comment: thanks @Samuel, your answer is missing one point , where I wanted multiple structs of {type, quantity, amount} to all go under each other , ie, 3 columns rather than 6 columns, but I figured it by creating 3 tables and union all instead. Regardless I accepted it as it's super detailed & correct.

Comment: @TheeBen Thank you. I understood now your question better. Indeed, there is a faster and better solution for you. The unnest structure you provided need to be unnest once again. Please see above.